# Cannot download files from WebDAV server using Ubuntu file explorer

Tags: nautilus, webdav

I am using WebDAV server, which maps Windows folder onto WebDAV. I can connect to this WebDAV resource using standard Windows explorer. The files are shown in folders and editors like Microsoft Word successfully save changes directly into WebDAV server. When I connect to this WebDAV server via Ubuntu standard file explorer I see the files but actually cannot download or copy them. I used LibreOffice, PDF viewer and text-file editor and all of them fail to download file from server. What can I do to troubleshoot my WebDAV server?